# Which admin/admin role is required when getting admin consent for your app?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

An app needs admin consent when using the [client credential grant flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). I was curious which kind of admin/[admin role](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-office-365-admin-roles-da585eea-f576-4f55-a1e0-87090b6aaa9d) is required for this consent. Does it have to be a global admin or can it be something more restrictive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Graphs Admin role; Microsoft has rolled administration of most things into the Global Admin role. However, there are steps you can take to grant access here; whether you want to follow them given the requirements is up to you. the steps are described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/02/granting-tenant-admin-consent-for-microsoft-graph-explorer/

> ### Giving Consent for All Users for Microsoft Graph Explorer
>
> This error is occurring because the user trying to use the graph explorer is trying to utilize a v2 permission that requires admin consent. The permissions/scopes regarding the v2 endpoint are described in the link here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes
>
> ### Resolution
>
> To resolve this issue, the Microsoft Graph explorer provides a convenient pre-developed URL for users to give the Global Admin of the tenant in order to grant admin consent on behalf of all users in the tenant. This is currently the only way to let users use the Microsoft Graph Explorer to get access to the Microsoft Graph API with permissions that require Admin Consent.
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

You can also read how to do it from a more dev-friendly page here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Comment: So i can assume that there is no other way but to let a global admin consent to my app? So i basically have to give a user global admin priviliges in the office 365 admin center (so he is able to consent to apps) ?

Comment: @MichaelHufnagel Yes, AFAIK; I have not done this with Graph (I don't use it) but I have run into the issue with other Office 365 apps that don't have standalone admin controls (Flow, Teams bots, etc.).

Comment: The scopes that require Admin Consent are _extremely_ farreaching. For example, if you have the Application scope  `Mail.Read`, you can literally read any mailbox from your own to the CEO's. :) This is why these scopes require a Global Admin to authorize.

Comment: @Marc LaFleur Makes sense ^^. 
Thank you both for your help.